# How to Deploy only the sub-modules using maven deploy?

Tags: maven

How do i deploy only the sub-modules of the project?
i have a project as;

```
ProjectA
 -  Submodule B
 - Submodlue C
 - Submodule D
```

The submodules are packaged as jar and is deployed to maven repo.how can only the sub -modules be deployed to the maven repository and not the main project?

Answer (score 82):

Put this in module(s)(or module's pom.xml) that you don't want to deploy:

```
<properties>
  <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
</properties>
```

Since this is inherited by submodules, you have to put this in submodules that you do want to deploy:

```
<properties>
  <maven.deploy.skip>false</maven.deploy.skip>
</properties>
```

Comment: The skip property will be `true` in all submodules... so nothing at all will be deployed....

Comment: @dokaspar just set the skip property to `false` for all the submodules you want to deploy...

Comment: Also if you have a situation where you need to deploy overlapping sets of module, use profiles. Example: module is [m1, m2, m3] user setting-foo deploy[m1, m2] and under 'setting-bar' deploy[m2, m3] ref: [maven-profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Answer (score 19):

Another suggestion could be doing the following:

```
mvn deploy -pl SubModuleB
```

Comment: This is very simple and easy solution.

Comment: This way the parent pom is not published and causes the project who references the module to fail when building

Answer (score 11):

This is working on my side
Put the plugin declaration in the parent pom , skip=true, but set inherited=false.
This prevents from repeating the <maven.deploy.skip> on each child modules.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me. Similar to other answer except added missing plugins element. Add to parent POM.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You also need to re-enable the deploy for each sub-module that you want to deploy with a <skip>false</skip>

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [technique described in my blog](https://community.jboss.org/people/ozizka/blog/2013/07/06/how-to-speed-up-maven-builds-disabling-unused-plugins).

In this case, you'd disable `default-deploy` (or what the name is) in the root `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And then enable it for submodules:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the maven-deploy-plugin in the POM of a module to exclude it from the deploy:

```
<build>
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <configuration>
       <skip>true</skip>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ...
</build>
```

Comment: Hi Raghu ...couldnt make it work ...tried putting the code into parent pm,but it gives the same result